# on duplicate key wierd issue

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using sql query in my project, with next code:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "insert into open_offer_counters (offer_id, udid, open_counter) values #{opened_events.join(", ")} on duplicate key update open_counter = open_counter + 1"
```

I've added

```
add_index :open_offer_counters, :offer_id, :unique => true
add_index :open_offer_counters, :udid,  :unique => true
```

into one of migrations. But when i'm trying to add some record with only 1 duplicate key, that doesnt works, but instead update key happens. Basically this code works if only 2 keys(offer_id and udid) are different. If any of them match other one, AR updates my open_counter. How do i make update open_counter if only 2 keys matched(offer_id and udid)?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by added

```
add_index(:open_offer_counters, [:offer_id, :udid], :unique => true)
```

instead of

```
add_index :open_offer_counters, :offer_id, :unique => true
add_index :open_offer_counters, :udid,  :unique => t
```